# How do I apply conditional formatting on a pair of rows in Excel?

Tags: python, excel, xlwings

I am using Python and xlwings to insert data in an excel worksheet. The data looks like below in excel:

```
   A   B   C   D   E
1  10  20  5  15   30
2  15  10  12 15   20
3  Empty
4  22  11  5  8    9
5  10  5  12  2    9
6  Empty
```

My aim is for each pair of rows: 1,2 and 4,5 , to change the background colors of the cells based on which number on each column is smaller.

Examples:

A1 < A2, then A1 will be black and A2 red.

B1 > B2, then B1 will be red and B2 black.

D1 = D2, then D1, D2 will be both black.

I use `xlwings.Range("Sheet1", "A1").color = (..., ..., ...)` to do what I am talking about but I would like to use Excel to do that.

My formula for conditional formatting is the following:

```
=AND($B1>$B2, ISNUMBER($B1), ISNUMBER($B2))
```

It formats correctly the first cell of the pair, ex. B1 but not B2.

Comment: You have been here long enough to know you have to show effort.

Comment: I have added the formula I use so far.